# WebRTC - how to send voice stream from chrome to endpoint via sip

Tags: webrtc

experts! Issue - we have an equipment which can receive voice stream via sip. We can use standart application to do this (and it works) but we want to send voice stream from browser (i.e. Chrome)
clients and "sevrer" (means equipment) are in our local net
I've discoverded WebRTC, and tried  to get MediaStream from Chrome.
My code

```
    var constraints={audio:true};
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(stream) {
alert(stream)
   })
.catch(function(err){.
   alert(err)
});
} else {
alert('getUserMedia is not supported in this browser.');
}
```

But what should I do to send voice stream to equipment?
I know "coonection string" to equipment (e.g sip:192.168.22.123:5060)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a signaling server which can exchange an offer and answer, as well as ICE candidates. A SIP INVITE can include SDP which can be provided to the `setRemoteDescription` method of an `RTCPeerConnection` object in the browser. Then, create an answer and send that back as a SIP 200. I recommend doing some reading about the basics of WebRTC before you post again. You really have not shown any effort on the side of WebRTC, only in capturing a media stream from the browser, which is actually not a part of WebRTC itself, only often used in conjunction. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/real-time-communication-with/9781449371869/ch01.html